# Using oracle database to manage a small firm

Tags: database, oracle

I want to know if am been hired as an independent Oracle database administrator in a small firm, do I have to use Oracle universal installer only to create and manage their database or is there any special software recommended by Oracle corporation for that?

Comment: we made the installer to help you install and create a database - use it. You might want to create your own templates for the database creation assistant (DBCA) though https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/07/12/use-your-own-templates-in-dbca-to-create-databases/

Comment: This question would probably attract more and better answers if asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Shouldn't you know this if you are being employed as a DBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then:
Oracle recommended to use OUI (Oracle Universal Installer) to manage and create (only these are possible) only Oracle databases.